# Blocked apps script add-on due to scope

Tags: google-apps-script

**Problem**: My add-on is blocked by some companies.

**Context**:  I've written an Google Apps Script add-on for Sheets that shows under Project Properties -> Scope:
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"

**Error**:  But an error from a particular company suggests that the scope being broadcast is "scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" (a more broad scope).  This broader scope is blocked, but the more restrictive scope (above and as seen in my project properties) is ok according to the company.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you ask this question in the [Developing Add-on for GSuite community](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)  It's a good question, but I'm not sure if it's really "on topic" for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the app on your account, can you go to:

https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

and then uninstall the app (revoke permissions)? Then, when you try to use it again, you should get the same permissions popup the client gets. I'd cross check that first to see it first hand.

Maybe you can also make sure that the proper version of the add-on is deployed. Perhaps you added the @OnlyCurrentDoc tag later and it doesn't reflect on the current version.